# Korselt number of pq

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Let $\alpha$ be an integer such that $\alpha\neq p+q-1$ and $gcd(p,\alpha)=1$. Suppose that $N$ is an $\alpha$-Korselt number and $2p<q<3p$. Then $\alpha\in\{3q-5p+3,\frac{3p+q-1}{2},q-p+1\}$. Here, $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

PROOF: $q=2p+s$ with $1\le s\le p-1$. By using another lemma, $\alpha=p+r$ with $2\le r\le 2p-1$, and $\alpha\neq p$. Now, using again another lemma, $r$ divides $q-1=2p+s-1$. Then there exists an integer $k>0$ such that $kr=2p+s-1$.  Several cases have to be considered.
case 1: Suppose that $k\ge 4$; then we obtain the inequality $r\le\frac{2p+s-1}{4}$.   Since , in addition, we have by another lemma, $p+s-r\le p-1$, then inequality $r\le\frac{2p+s-1}{4}$ yields $p+s-r\le p-1<2(p+s-r)$. But, by another lemma, $p+s-r$ divides $p-1$; consequently, we get $p-1=p+s-r$ so that $r=s+1$. Therefore, $\alpha=p+r=q-p+1$. And we have another cases when $k=3,2,1$.    Now , I can not understand how $p-1<2(p+s-r)$.

Comment: What is a "Korselt number of $pq$"? What is an $\alpha$-Korselt number?

Comment: N is an alpha-Korselt number iff p-alpha divides N-alpha for all prime divisor p of N

Comment: Is $N$ supposed to be related in some way to $p$ and/or $q$?

Comment: In this case N=pq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $s\ge1$ we get $s>-1$, $3s>-3$, $s-1<4s+2$, ${s-1\over2}<2s+1$, $p+{s-1\over2}< p+2s+1$. Then from $r\le{2p+s-1\over4}$ we get $$2r\le{2p+s-1\over2}=p+{s-1\over2}< p+2s+1$$ But $2r<p+2s+1$ is equivalent to $p-1<2(p+s-r)$.